# pass retrived data to limit mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch sent_count value from my table and use that retrived value to 'LIMIT'. Is it possible??. Thanks in advance.

```
           "SELECT
            message.id,
            message.message,
            message.sent_count as select_count,

            number_dlr.message_id,
            number_dlr.contact

            FROM message
            INNER JOIN number_dlr ON message.id=number_dlr.message_id
            WHERE
            message.status='2' AND
            number_dlr.status ='2'
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT select_count
            "
```

Comment: Your idea doesn't make sense.  Each message has a `select_count`.  The `LIMIT` applies to the entire query.  Sample data and desired results would help clarify.

Comment: My second table contains more than one record with same message_id, from those records I want to select limited value based on select count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to fetch sent_count value from my table and use that retrived value to 'LIMIT'. Is it possible?.

No, unfortunately, the numbers in LIMIT clauses have to be constants, or have to be bound before the query starts running. [The documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Comment: Thank you O.Jones